# Which version of firefox will support Web SQL?

Tags: javascript, firefox, html

I'm developing an app that needs offline storage SQL.

I try:

```
    if (window.openDatabase) {
        window.db = window.openDatabase("app", "", "my app db name", 1024*1024);
    }
```

this works great on Chrome but doesn't work on my Firefox 3.6

What version of firefox will support openDatabase?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Mozilla have said they will never implement it according to this thread:

[HTML5 IndexedDB, Web SQL Database and browser wars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971813/html5-indexeddb-web-sql-database-and-browser-wars)

Answer (score 7):

I believe FF is working towards implementing [IndexedDB](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/comparing-indexeddb-and-webdatabase/) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Default location for WebSQL DB in case of Firefox:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\mlolddya.default\databases\
```

For Chrome:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases\
```

for safari:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apple Computer\Safari\Databases\
```

new version of FF are not using WebSQL they are moved to IndexedDB.which is good 
no need to give support for two different db if you dont want to give support for Safari

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested to know what browsers support what you can check out [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com). In particular about local storage see [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=storage)

**Edit**: Oops! I didn't realize this was a year old.