# openDatabase is not defined

Tags: html

I have the following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
var dbo = openDatabase('HelloWorld');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and I'm getting in firebug:
openDatabase is not defined.

Comment: What sort of database are you expecting to open? My best guess is IndexedDB which is still experimental in Firefox 4 and needs to be accessed via mozIndexedDB.open - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB/IndexedDB_primer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to open a SQL storage but Firefox has no such feature. Mozilla will never implement it. Have a look at this question: [Which version of firefox will support Web SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183977/which-version-of-firefox-will-support-web-sql)