# Is it possible to access an SQLite database from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, database, sqlite

I have a set of HTML files and a SQLite database, which I would like to access from the browser, using the file:// scheme. Is it possible to access the database and create queries (and tables) using JavaScript?

Comment: By `file:` scheme do you mean on the computer the *browser* is running on?

Comment: Yes. Currently I have a tool which creates a report (a bunch of images, html files and an sqlite database). I can simply open this report locally (i.e. $ google-chrome report_out/index.html). I would like to make this more interactive, so the javascript would read the generated data from the database and create statistics out of it.

Comment: i believe it'd be possible to make a connection via a WebSocket proxy, but it'd take quite a bit of work to set up

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Actually the answer is yes. Here is an example how you can do this: http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/

The bad thing is that it's with very limited support by the browsers.

More information here [HTML5 IndexedDB, Web SQL Database and browser wars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971813/html5-indexeddb-web-sql-database-and-browser-wars)

PS: As @Christoph said [Web SQL is no longer in active maintenance and the Web Applications Working Group does not intend to maintain it further](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) so look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB.

### SQL.js

*EDIT*

As @clentfort said, you can access SQLite database with client-side JavaScript by using [SQL.js](https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js).

Comment: FYI websql has been abandoned... Promote **[indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB)** instead.

Comment: But is it possible to connect to the already existing database? I already have a bunch of data in it, which I would like to process with javascript.

Comment: You can go with some server side stuff, or try Node.JS for this
https://codeforgeek.com/2014/07/node-sqlite-tutorial/

Answer (score 51):

You could use [**SQL.js**](https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js) which is the SQLlite lib compiled to JavaScript and store the database in the local storage introduced in HTML5.

Comment: local storage is very slow and clumsy... you should use indexedDB instead. Nonetheless this is a working solution i guess.

Comment: While localstorage isn't as nice as indexedDB, it is supported pretty much everywhere.  SQL.js doesn't use localstorage directly (it's in memory), so you only have to read from/write to localstorage on startup/shutdown, you could even save SQL.js's state on a server.  Good if you want the user to specifically save changes, bad if a user leaving without letting it save can break things.

Answer (score 23):

## Up to date answer

My fork of sql.js has now be merged into [the original version, on a dedicated repo](https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js).

The [good documentation](http://kripken.github.io/sql.js/documentation) is also available on the original repo.

## Original answer (outdated)

You should use the [newer version of **sql.js**](https://github.com/lovasoa/sql.js). It is a port of sqlite 3.8, has a [good documentation](http://lovasoa.github.io/sql.js/documentation) and is actively maintained (by me). It supports prepared statements, and BLOB data type.

Comment: Can I use sql.js for accessing (insert, update, read) SQLite database which is on server side.

Comment: @lovasoa If I use sql.js, can a fresh computer run my site and do the CRUD to its database (db stored in the same path with HTML folder) without doing any installations?

Comment: @JeafGilbert No. sql.js operates exclusively in-memory, nothing is persisted. If you want to write the database file on your filesystem, you will have to write that logic yourself.

Comment: @Abhee - No. sql.js would be for accessing a SQLite db on client only stored in the browser's localStorage. To access server side, you would need to be exposed the server side DB through  HTTP API's (eg. REST).

Answer (score 5):

One of the most interesting features in `HTML5` is the ability to store data locally and to allow the application to run offline. There are three different APIs that deal with these features and choosing one depends on what exactly you want to do with the data you're planning to store locally:

1. Web storage: For basic local storage with key/value pairs
2. Offline storage: Uses a manifest to cache entire files for offline
   use
3. Web database: For relational database storage

For more reference see [Introducing the HTML5 storage APIs](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/html5-storage-apis.html)

And how to use

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Store_data_in_the_HTML5_SQLite_database-19115.html

Comment: hehe, take a look into the second revision of your answer, there you can read it;)

Answer (score -6):

It is best to code with python and flask. If you use [WebSQL](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/) with JavaScript then it will only save the data for individual windows and not worldwide, as it is a browser cookie. [Flask](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/index.htm) is a python web server and once you make a page with it you can [import sqlite3](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sqlite.htm). Another way is to use php, but the main point is that using JavaScript is a bad idea.

P.S. Actually you can try using [loaclStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) i heard it can save data for as long as you want it to be saved.

Comment: It's a JavaScript question about browser storage options such as indexedDb so suggesting to not use javascript isn't really helpful.

Comment: *[localStorage] can save data for as long as you want it to be saved.* Absolutely not - it will persist the data only until a cleanup is triggered ("delete local data" in the browser). This is a good place to store data that you want to persist between sessions but not difficult to recreate after having been wiped.

Answer (score -9):

IMHO, the best way is to call Python using POST via AJAX and do everything you need to do with the DB within Python, then return the result to the javascript. json and sqlite support in Python is awesome and it's 100% built-in within even slightly recent versions of Python, so there is no "install this, install that" pain. In Python:

```
import sqlite3
import json
```

...that's all you need. It's part of every Python distribution.

@Sedrick Jefferson asked for examples, so (somewhat tardily) I have written up a [stand-alone back-and-forth between Javascript and Python here.](http://fyngyrz.com/?p=2802)

Comment: the question contains **"...which I would like to access from the browser..."**. so your  answer (with `python`) is out of the area (at least today, when it is not that easy to run python from a browser)

Comment: Nonetheless, it's the best way to do it. :)

Comment: The reason to want to use sqlite in the browser is to have fast and organized data storage client side without having to use HTTP. Talking to Python over HTTP would not be fast. Secondly, depended on python assumes you are exposing your SQLite DB to the open internet, which opens a bunch of security failure modes for hackers to pick at. If you are talking about building something for you on your private LAN, would be fine, but open internet apps ... nope. I am a full stack developer who uses Python daily.