# Access SQLite database from JavaScript application?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

We have an SQLite database lying around, which is curerntly filled from an external batch job.  The database is not very complex (essentially two tables in a 1:n relationship and some "catalog tables" holding lookup values).

We now have to add a user-frontend as well as some reporting. At one moment in time only one user is using the frontend, however, this should be possible from everywhere in our network (= wherever access to the SQLite file is possible).

What's the easiest way to create an easy-to-use frontend with as little effort as possible? I thought about using HTML/JS, but haven't found out how to access a local SQLite DB with JS (is this even possible? we could grant the application such access rights of course, however, do browsers even support this?)

If HTML/JS is not an option without a dedicated server, is there any other possiblity to get this done with little effort? We do not want to end up with MS Access... :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192643/is-it-possible-to-access-an-sqlite-database-from-javascript

Comment: Don't think so, in the other thread there is only local storage presented, however, it should access a DB file on a network share instead (reachable by the system's file system of course).

Comment: There is a sqlite implementation in pure javascript that you could try. I's mainly written for NodeJS but is said to work clientside as well. The main problem however will be getting access to the database file. https://github.com/kripken/sql.js

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HTA application](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472841) if not afraid of safety problems. Rename your html file to *.hta, make ODBC connection to your database then:

```
var Connection = new ActiveXObject ('ADODB.Connection');
Connection.Open (<ODBC-name>);
var Records = new ActiveXObject ('ADODB.Recordset');
Records.Open (Sql, Connection, 0, 2);
```

See the [Properties & Methods for ADO Recordset Object](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_recordset.asp).

Comment: Pretty sure that he doesn't want to install a new ODBC-driver on all the clients though.

Comment: He can make connection string: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite3-odbc-driver/

Comment: Yes but all the computers that were to access this file would need http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/ to be installed first. However, that driver seems to be tested only up to Windows 2000 so it might not work on newer systems.

Comment: They like «access a local SQLite DB with JS». It possible without driver?

Comment: Should be possible with the js-driver I posted in the comments above.