# Change a html element from a separate file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to acheive having 2 open html files open and be able to manipulate on with the other.

not sure where to start. I am attempting to create a cricket scoreboard layout and have the first html file which will be displayed on an electronic scoreboard while a game is being played and want to be able to have buttons in another file which will be used on another computer or tablet to change the wickets and runs.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: And you have tried what so far? Any research or attempt of your own? Or just looking for someone to do it for you?

Comment: first show what you have done so far.show your code

Answer (score 0):

[Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAHJ5.png)

Having a webserver to handle this would be ideal but if that is not the case.

- You may need a database to store the score which can be accessed by both the pages. While one page would write/update the score other page (scoreboard) would primarily be fetching the data to show it. Check this to find how to access and updpate sqlite. [Is it possible to access an SQLite database from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192643/is-it-possible-to-access-an-sqlite-database-from-javascript)

> you can access SQLite database with client-side JavaScript by using
>   [SQL.js.](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js)

- For the scoreboard page, access data from sqlite db and auto-refresh so that the latest scores are shown. Add below `html` tag to refresh every 5 seconds.

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >
```