# Getting data from existing sqlite DB into webpage

Tags: javascript, sqlite, web-services

I have desktop application which creates SqLite DB.

I would like to use that data to make reports on a local static web page. 
However I'm not sure how to go about connecting to an existing DB - I understand there are security issues with this.

is this possible with JavaScript ? and how would i go about this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to pass the data from the templates like so:

```
def index(request):
    # Calculate your precious data here, for example using the django.core.serializers class:
    data = serializers.serialize('json', FooModel.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'templates/index.html', {'data': data})
```

Then in your `templates/index.html` you could do something like this:

```
<script>
    window.data = {{data|default:"{}"|safe}};
</script>
```

*Check out the [safe filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe).*

This way, you get all your data from backend to frontend with your initial request without creating any additional requests, or communicating with your DB directly with JS.

---

Another option is using `fetch`:

You could create a view (you could use Django REST framework but that's up to what you're trying to use it for, the main idea remains the same anyway):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseNotAllowed, JsonResponse
from django.core import serializers
from .models import FooModel # for example

def myview(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['POST'], "Only POST is allowed to this URL.")
    # Get your precious data, let's use the same example as before:
    data = serializers.serialize('json', FooModel.objects.all())
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Register it in your `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api/retrievepreciousdata', views.myview),
    ...
]
```

And then we can use `fetch` to retrieve it:

```
fetch("/api/retrievepreciousdata", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        //For CSRF protection:
        //I use `js-cookie` to get the cookies, it's up to you really
        "X-CSRFToken": Cookies.get("csrftoken"),
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    },
}).then(response => {
    if(!response.ok) {
        console.log("Dang it, the response isn't OK... Response code is", response.status);
    }
    return response.json()
}).then(json => {
    console.log("I did it! My precious data is:", json);
}).catch(e => {
    console.log("Dang it, something went wrong while retrieving my precious data:", e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to read data from SQLlite Db  from a static webpage I suggest you read the following thread [Is it possible to access an SQLite database from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192643/is-it-possible-to-access-an-sqlite-database-from-javascript)

Try this also [SQL.js](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js) (its mention in the above thread)