# WebSQL vs SQLlite vs IndexDB - For HTML5 which database is better?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, mobile

I want to use a database in my mobile application. I prefer SQLite but it has a connection issue. I have problems connecting the SQLite database to html5. Do you have any suggestions on which database would help me the most?

Comment: I think you will find the next link usefull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192643/is-it-possible-to-access-an-sqlite-database-from-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution for my question..
WebSQL , Indexeddb not working in android app.

I have used cordova plugin to connect SQLLITE database. Now my html file working with cordova SQLITE plugin.