# Is it possible to run an SQL query on a local db file (not running on some server)?

Tags: javascript, sql, database, client

I have some local.db file and just want to run some sql query on it. Do I need to run a localhost server and then somehow connect to it in order to run proceed? (This is for a simple client-side project with html,js,css)

Comment: SQL is a specialized programming language operating on data stored in particular ways. You can use some simple tools to perform some of the operations available through a DBMS on plain files, but it's a stretch to call that "SQL".

Comment: It is hard to answer the question without knowing what type of database file it is (i.e., MySQL, MS-SQL, Oracle, etc.).

Comment: @Frelling Its just a sqlite .db file

Comment: @jimbob542 One more question. what are you using to run JavaScript, is it Node.js or are you just running some basic JavaScript within an HTML in the browser?

Comment: @Frelling Just basic JS functions contained in <script> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jimbob542 Thanks for suffering the game of 20 questions. Given that you are looking to access SQLite data from within an HTML using JavaScript, please refer to this SO answer 
[Is it possible to access an SQLite database from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192643/is-it-possible-to-access-an-sqlite-database-from-javascript) There are some limitations, but hopefully it will do what you need.