# How to connect to a Sqlite db from an HTML file via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, browserify

I would like to insert data into a `SQlite3` db by pressing a button from an `HTML` file.
In order to achieve this, I wrote a `JS` script.
Unfortunately, when I press the button, I get this error message in my console.log:

> script.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Then, I tried to convert my JS file with `browserify` but then I got this error:

> Cannot read property '_handle' of undefined

Here my HTML and JS codes to reproduce the error:

HTML:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label>SQLite3</label>
        <button type="button">Connection</button>   
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function addData() {
    const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
    let db = new sqlite3.Database('./data.db');
    db.run('INSERT INTO info (result) VALUES (10)', function(err, row) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
        console.log("entry added to table");
    });
}
addData();
```

Comment: does this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192643/is-it-possible-to-access-an-sqlite-database-from-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Browserify works around the problem that browsers don't have native support for the Node.js module system.

Browserify does **not** work around most other APIs that are provided but Node.js but not browsers. For example, Node.js has the `fs` module which allows you to access the file system of the computer the code is running on. Browsers, on the other hand, don't allow access except in very particular and limited ways.

Since `new sqlite3.Database('./data.db')` tries to read data from a file, it will not work in a browser.

Use a different API that is supported by browsers instead (such as [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) or [Web Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).

Alternatively, if you want to *share* data between browsers, use Node.js to run a web server (e.g. with Express.js) and write a web service through which the database can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to sqlite databawe from client side you have to connect from server side language. Perhaps you can use **NodeJS** as server side programming language.

follow those steps then it will work

**STEP1**
Download and install node js from https://nodejs.org/en/download/

**STEP2**
Install npm by folloy this instruction
https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm

**STEP3**
Create Node js project by following this guides http://cassandrawilcox.me/setting-up-a-node-js-project-with-npm/

**STEP4**
Now you can install sqlite3 via npm.

After that you have to run server. If you are beginner then follow this
https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/

Comment: I have installed the nodeJS for sqlite3 via this command `npm install sqlite3`. Is it not correct?

Comment: @HDave it is correct, but you still can't utilize the SQLite database from the client side (e.g. in your HTML or script served in the browser). You'll need to run it on the server side, such as in a request / route handler.

Comment: @H.Dave I've edited the instruction follow this maybe it will work for you.

Comment: @Nafish Ahmed if I start my JS file via the shell with this command `node script`, my code works properly and I can insert data into my db. However, I block on how to trigger this action from the button embedded into my `html`. In other words, how can I activate the server without using the shell?

Comment: Use Ejs modules to render template