# How to use javascript to query db and create array

Tags: javascript, sql, django

I have a database with the following table:

`Product_table`

The product table has 3 columns; `product_name`, `product_info`, and `product_cost`

I need to query the database in order to pull all product names out, and put them in an array.

I know the SQL is `'SELECT product_name FROM product_table'` but I don't know how to implement that in javascript.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to access an SQLite database from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192643/is-it-possible-to-access-an-sqlite-database-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: See here if it helps: [Is it possible to access an SQLite database from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192643/is-it-possible-to-access-an-sqlite-database-from-javascript)

Your question is very badly asked.

I suggest you to use node.js: https://nodejs.org/en/download/
It allows you to run javascript without browser.

And I assume the database is MySQL. Then u will need the mysql package:
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql
Refer the github documentation on how to install and use it.

Basically, you will use the `mysql` pacakge to make connection to your database (you need to provide the host/user/password), create database connection, then executes your SELECT query. The `mysql` package's `conn.query(sql, params)` already returns list of results in an array for you.

Comment: Okay, I appreciate your input. This is all pretty new to me. I am using SQLite3 and the database connection is defined in my Django settings.py file. This script runs on the 'index.html' page. I am pretty sure that the connection does not need to be defined in the script because it is already defined in the settings...correct me if I am wrong

Comment: that is an entirely different technology stack you are using. please specify it in your question.